# force postfix to use only one sender address

Tags: server, email, postfix

I have several servers that occasionally send alerts to me. Each alert comes from a different email address. However, my ISP (bluewin.ch) will only allow me to relay mails from my own email address. Hence the senders' names should be e.g. "nagios@mydomain", "munin@mydomain", "root.myserver@mydomain", etc., but the underlying address should always be the same, e.g. "me@bluewin.ch".

Is there a way to force Postfix to substitute all email addresses with "me@bluewin.ch" while preserving the name of the sender?